# How can I pass arguments to a PL/SQL procedure, while invoking it from ant sql task?

Tags: sql, oracle, ant, plsql

I have an ant target like-

```
<target name="run-patched-sql-file">
    <path id="antclasspath">
        <fileset dir="${weblogic.server.dir}/server/lib">
            <include name="*ojdbc6.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <property name="pathvar" refid="antclasspath"/>
    <filelist id="sql-files" dir="../../db/scripts/oracle/">
            <file name="scripts/scriptToExecute.sql"/>
    </filelist>
    <sql driver="${operationsDB.driver}" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${operationsDB.host}) (PORT=${operationsDB.port}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=${operationsDB.serviceName})))" userid="${operationsDB.user}" password="${OIM.DBPassword}" delimiter="/" delimitertype="row" keepformat="yes" onerror="continue" caching="true" escapeprocessing="no" classpathref="antclasspath">
        <path>
            <filelist refid="sql-files"/>
        </path>
    </sql>
</target>
```

Now scriptToExecute.sql expects an argument.
How can we pass this argument to sql script from ant task.

Comment: It depends on `scriptToExecute.sql`.

Comment: scriptToExecute.sql is-   DECLARE

DC_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := '&1';

BEGIN
 INSERT INTO PTY (PTY_KEYWORD,PTY_VALUE,PTY_UPDATE,PTY_UPDATEBY)
                 VALUES ('DCNamepty',DC_NAME,SYSDATE,'ADMIN');
 COMMIT;
END;

Comment: Unfortunately the SQL task doesn't support parametrized arguments, and in some cases such as DB2 stored procedures, the EXEC call is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE DC_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := '&1'; 
   BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO PTY (PTY_KEYWORD,PTY_VALUE,PTY_UPDATE,PTY_UPDATEBY) 
    VALUES ('DCNamepty',DC_NAME,SYSDATE,'ADMIN'); 
    COMMIT; 
    END;
```

This means, when you execute this `.sql` file. It will prompt for value to enter. As I can see for variable `DC_NAME` has variable substitution used as `&1`.

Comment: Yes, If you execute directly on sqlplus it would prompt for argument. Requirement is to  provide this argument through ANT task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template and some `copy` tasks to do `replacetokens` substitution:

```
<copy todir="." overwrite="true" verbose="true">
 <fileset dir="." includes="scriptToExecute.tpl"/>
 <mapper type="glob" from="*.tpl" to="*.sql"/>
 <filterchain>
  <replacetokens>
    <token key="DC_NAME" value="the name of my DC"/>
  </replacetokens>
 </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Here is `scriptToExecute.tpl` note the `@DC_NAME@` template token:

```
INSERT INTO PTY (PTY_KEYWORD,PTY_VALUE,PTY_UPDATE,PTY_UPDATEBY) 
VALUES ('DCNamepty','@DC_NAME@',SYSDATE,'ADMIN'); 
COMMIT;
```

Another way is to add a `FilterChain` using `ExpandProperties` to achieve a similar goal. The query template would then use parameter expansion: `${DC_NAME}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running sqlplus direct?

```
<exec executable="sqlplus" 
      dir="./" output="${logfile}" failOnError="true">
  <arg value="${db_user}/${db_passwd}@${tnsalias_or_tnsurl}" />
  <arg value="@scripts/scriptToExecute.sql"/> 
  <arg value="the_value_for_param_1"/> 
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it like

```
<target name="run-patched-sql-file">
    <path id="antclasspath">
        <fileset dir="${weblogic.server.dir}/server/lib">
            <include name="*ojdbc6.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <property name="pathvar" refid="antclasspath"/>
    <filelist id="sql-files" dir="../../db/scripts/oracle/">
            <file name="scripts/scriptToExecute.sql"/>
    </filelist>
    <sql driver="${operationsDB.driver}" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${operationsDB.host}) (PORT=${operationsDB.port}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=${operationsDB.serviceName})))" userid="${operationsDB.user}" password="${operationsDB.DBPassword}" delimiter="/" delimitertype="row" keepformat="yes" onerror="continue" caching="true" escapeprocessing="no" classpathref="antclasspath">
        <![CDATA[
            DECLARE 
            DC_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := '${DataCenter.NAME}'; 
            BEGIN 
                    INSERT INTO pty (pty_keyword,pty_value,pty_update,pty_updateby) 
                        VALUES ('DCNamepty',DC_NAME,SYSDATE,'ADMIN'); 
            COMMIT; 
            END; 
        ]]>
    </sql>
</target>
```